# Trying to understand the development of Number System

Tags: book-recommendation, number-systems

I want to understand how number system evolved from scratch.

I am looking for a book which starts with natural numbers, explains their origin, explains how addition and multiplication is defined on them rigorously. Then how integers, rationals were developed, operations on them, and finally reals. I want to understand all this very rigorously.

I would like to have suggestions for reference books.

Thank you.

P.S. The reason behind asking this question was, from recently I have started feeling something unreal about numbers. I mean when I think about decimals whether recurring or non-recurring, finite or infinite, irrationals like π or e, I just get blank and keep thinking, what these numbers actually are? What they represents? How they arrive? And many such questions. I don't know why and how these started but I am feeling very uncomfortable dealing with numbers. Honestly I am very very serious about this issue of mine and that's why wanted to understand evolution of number system. I thought there might be some books about this construction.

Comment: This is too broad and too vague.  Have you, say, studied any of the standard constructions of the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through construction of reals from rationals via Dedekind cuts from baby rudin but I don't have any idea about the development from naturals to rationals

Comment: Well, are you asking about the history of these things or are you interested in a modern, axiomatic treatment?  Really, your question is extremely vague and enormously broad.

Comment: Historically the 19th century development of rigour was backwards, from complex numbers to reals to rationals to natural numbers, as it was successively seen that the foundations were not actually present.

Comment: Not history.. modern axiomatic treatment

Comment: So, look up the Peano axioms and start there.

Comment: See e.g. Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis (Springer, 2011)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Real_Numbers_and_Real_Analysis/r0qcU9U2_I4C)

Comment: Voting to close the question because it lacks focus.

Comment: Maybe also S.Feferman, [The Number Systems](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Number_Systems_Foundations_of_Algebr/oD6S71TMyn4C)

Comment: @lulu This seems very focused and not at all vague to me.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, you say you want a rigorous treatment, not a historical one.

There is a standard answer to this question, "Foundations of Analysis" by Landau. I've only ever glanced at it, and what I saw didn't make me want to look at it any further.

I have to say, I've never seen a treatment of the natural numbers I liked in an algebra or analysis book.

You can get a more sensible treatment of N, based on cardinals, in a set theory book like "Introduction to Set Theory" by Jech and Hrbacek, though they leave some details for you to work out as exercises.

Jacobson's "Basic Algebra I" has a presentation of N I like less, but it has the steps from N to Z and from Z to Q. The step from Z to Q can be found in any abstract algebra book under "field of fractions of an integral domain".

You said you'd read the construction of R from Q as Dedekind cuts, so I'm not sure what more you'd like than that.